# ADT destroys git repository on import

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I've got the following problem.

I want to import an existing android project, that was freshly git cloned to my workspace, into my **ADT** projects list.

Before I import the project into **ADT** by 'Import'->'Existing Android Code Into Workspace', git tells me that directory is indeed a git repository, afterwards git tells me that it isn't any more.

Did one of you encounter this before?

Comment: sidenote: a lot, but not all, of the nonempty files in the .git directory are empty after the import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try import>projects from git under the Git subfolder in the menu of options

Comment: That helped flawlessly. Thank you very much!